# Transforming js array such that a numeric value is added

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

My base data..

```
[{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'A',
        val: 20
    },{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'B','
        val: 5
    },{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'C',
        val: 10
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'A',
        val: 30
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'B',
        val: 10
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'C',
        val: 20
    }];
```

I would like to transform it to the following format..

```
[{
            dim:'val'
        x: 'Jan',
            nval: 20 //same as base object val
        },{
            dim:'val'
            x: 'Jan',
            nval: 25// 20+5 -> above nval value + base object val
        },{
            dim:'val'
            x: 'Jan',
            nval: 35//25+10
        },{
            dim:'val'
            x: 'Feb',
            val: 65//35+30
        },{
            dim:'val'
            x: 'Feb',
            nval: 75
        },{
            dim:'val'
            x: 'Feb',
            nval: 95
        }];
```

Above js array has a property dim which has a fixed value 'val', the property x has the same value of the base object's month.
The property nval is such that the property in the first object of the array has the same value of the base object's val. After that base object's val get's added to nval of prev object in new array.

I hope I have been able to explain what I need.. please do ask if you have any doubts/ questions..

The new javascript array I should be able to create using map but how do I create the nval from val..

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: What have  you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```js
var newObject=[];
var tempDate=0;
var base =[{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'A',
        val: 20
    },{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'B',
        val: 5
    },{
        month: 'Jan',
        cat: 'C',
        val: 10
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'A',
        val: 30
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'B',
        val: 10
    },{
        month: 'Feb',
        cat: 'C',
        val: 20
    }];

for(var prop in base)
{
  newObject.push({
    'dim':'val',
    'x':base[prop]['month'],
    'nval':tempDate + base[prop]['val']
  });
  tempDate=tempDate + base[prop]['val'];
}

console.log(newObject);
```